# Query the results from with() relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I have a with() relationship, each customer having assigned orders. I try to return the orders only for a certain period, like this:

```
if (isset($filters["date_from"]) && strlen($filters["date_from"]) > 0) {
     $value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($filters["date_from"]));
     $sales_by_customer = $sales_by_customer->with(array("orders" => function ($query) use ($value) {
          $query->whereDate("created_at", '>=', $value);
     }));
}
```

As you can see I want to return for each client only the orders from a certain period. But right now it doesn't take into account my query and it simply returns all orders for each client. 
Any idea how to obtain what I want. Thank you all for your time!

Comment: Assuming `$sales_by_customer` is already defined, you need to load the relationship. Try using `$sales_by_customer = $sales_by_customer->load(array("orders" => function ($query) use ($value) {
          $query->where("created_at", '>=', $value);
     }));`

Replace `whereDate` with `where.`

Answer (score 0):

Replace `load` with `with` if `$sales_by_customer` isn't already a collection.

```
if (isset($filters["date_from"]) && strlen($filters["date_from"]) > 0) {
     $value = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($filters["date_from"]));
     $sales_by_customer = $sales_by_customer->load(array("orders" => function ($query) use ($value) {
          $query->where("created_at", '>=', $value);
     }));
}
```

Comment: Method load is undefined at this point in query, the problem was much simpler apparently, I will post the answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `$sales_by_customer` is a single customer, to fetch all the order created between specific time.

```
$sales_by_customer->orders->where("created_at", '>=', $value)->all();
```

If `$sales_by_customer` is a collection of multiple customers then you need to run where query inside a foreach loop.

```
foreach($sales_by_customer as $customerSale) {
   $customerSale->orders->where("created_at", '>=', $value)->all();
}
```

Comment: `$sales_by_customer->orders()->where("created_at", '>=', $value)->get();`

Comment: I have tested it, getting this error while using get() method . `Missing argument 1 for Illuminate\Support\Collection::get()` but working perfect with all()

Comment: Did you change `orders` to `orders()`?? The first will get all relations, and you're doing a where in a collection, hence the need to use `all`. The second will query the relation on the database and return only the matched results.

Comment: Ohh Yes got it, Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**
Apparently the problem was that for some reason I cannot user whereDate and I had to use a simple where clause with some changes to the format I get the date (in DB created_at has the following format: `Y-m-d H:i:s` and my filter date had this format: `Y-m-d`)
So the solution looks like this:

```
if (isset($filters["date_from"]) && strlen($filters["date_from"]) > 0) {
     $value = date('Y-m-d 00:00:00', strtotime($filters["date_from"]));
     $sales_by_customer = $sales_by_customer->with(array("orders" => function ($query) use ($value) {
          $query->where("created_at", '>=', $value);
     }));
}
```